# pandas.crosstab slicing with added totals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am really struggling with dataframes currently.
By running the code: (res_sum = name of dataframe)

```
summary_table = pd.crosstab(index=[res_sum["Type"],res_sum["Size"]],
                        columns=res_sum["Found"],margins=True)
summary_table = summary_table.div(summary_table["All"] / 100, axis=0)
```

Results in:

```
Found                 Exact   Near     No    All
Type        Size                            
X           10          0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
            100         0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            500         0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            1000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            5000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
Y           10          0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            100         0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
            500         0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            1000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            5000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
....... (more)
All                     5.0   65.0   30.0  100.0
```

I want something like this:

```
Found                 Exact   Near     No    All
Type        Size                            
X           10          0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
            100         0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            500         0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            1000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            5000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
Total X                 0.0   80.0   20.0
Y           10          0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            100         0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
            500         0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            1000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            5000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
Total Y                 0.0   80.0   20.0
.......(more)
All                     5.0   65.0   30.0  100.0
```

This doesn't seem to be possible within pd.crosstab, so I tried to make subsets of each type, and after that paste the dataframes together again. It sorta works, but it removes all the totals. For example, the code:

```
x5 = summary_table.loc(axis=0)[['X'], slice(None)]
x6 = summary_table.loc(axis=0)[['Y'], slice(None)]

frames = [x5, x6]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

results in this, which completely ignores the "margins=True" from the pd.crosstable. Adding "margins=True"  to the dataframe.loc does not work.

```
Found                 Exact   Near     No    All
Type        Size                            
X           10          0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
            100         0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
            500       100.0    0.0    0.0  100.0
            1000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            5000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
Y           10          0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
            100         0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            500         0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            1000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
            5000        0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
```

To be a little clear why I need this, is that I need a summary of every type, and in the future there will be more values for each size, within a type (so not everything will be 100.0% anymore). Can anyone help me organise these dataframes? (Additionally I would be very happy if the "All"  at the end of every row is removed. It seems I can only add both "All" columns, even though I only need the column ones.)

EDIT BY REQUEST:

the snippit of data that I used (I changed the type to X, Y, Z, in the question, but these work fine also:

```
Found   Size    Type
Exact   500     INV
Near    100     DEL
Near    500     DEL
Near    1000    DEL
Near    5000    DEL
Near    100     INS
Near    500     INS
Near    1000    INS
Near    1000    INV
Near    5000    INV
Near    10      DUP
Near    500     DUP
Near    1000    DUP
Near    5000    DUP
No      10      DEL
No      10      INS
No      5000    INS
No      10      INV
No      100     INV
No      100     DUP
```

Comment: People will find it easier to answer if you can post a small sample of your input (and then make the output you're currently getting and the output you want to get correspond to that input).  That way people can paste it into their code and make sure their solution is doing what you want.

Comment: See edited question

Comment: May be pass normalize ='columns' parameter to pd.crosstab

Comment: I tried this solution also a few days ago, and after trying again now it didn't provide the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
appenddf=df.eq(100).sum(level=[0])# get the additional row 


appenddf=appenddf.div(appenddf.All,axis=0).mul(100) # get the percentage by the column count of total count 
appenddf
Out[465]:
      Exact  Near    No    All
Type
X       0.0  80.0  20.0  100.0
Y       0.0  80.0  20.0  100.0

appenddf.index=appenddf.index+'Total'# adjust the index 
appenddf=appenddf.assign(Size=np.nan).set_index('Size',append=True)# adding the Size to the appenddf


pd.concat([df,appenddf]).sort_index(level=0)
Out[484]: 
               Exact   Near     No    All
Type   Size                              
X      10.0      0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
       100.0     0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
       500.0     0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
       1000.0    0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
       5000.0    0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
XTotal NaN       0.0   80.0   20.0  100.0
Y      10.0      0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
       100.0     0.0    0.0  100.0  100.0
       500.0     0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
       1000.0    0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
       5000.0    0.0  100.0    0.0  100.0
YTotal NaN       0.0   80.0   20.0  100.0
```

Comment: I think this did the trick! thank you :). (I will look into it further tomorrow, but thanks a bunch!)

Comment: Your solution does indeed work, but I still have 1 problem, It also results in an "AllTotal" row, right below the "All" row (not shown in your example, but they are there in my situation apparantly). Is there a way to remove that one? (I don't know if by stack overflow conventions I can show my new code + results in an edited question?)

Comment: After some struggling, I found the answer myself. Adding
df = df.drop(["AllTotal"]) In the end does the trick

Comment: Could you help me one more time? the line `appenddf=df.eq(100).sum(level=[0])` is giving me much trouble, because it only looks for 100, but not if it is 25 or anything else between 0-100. I tried for hours to fix this, but nothing I put in `df.eq(here)` works. Not even int. Is there any way that this code can accept other values than 100?

Comment: sorry, I was literally busy for hours for this, but finally found it myself: `appenddf=df.gt(0).sum(level=[0])` did the trick. I guess gt means "greater than" and eq means "equal to", but man is the documentation not clear on this! [link]https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html[link]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subtotals = df.groupby(level=['Type']).mean()`
to compute the subtotals. Then

```
label_order = ['{}{}'.format(pre,label) for label in subtotals.index 
                                        for pre in ['', 'Total_']] + ['All']
```

generates the desired label order. Finally, `df = df.loc[label_order]` reorders the rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'All': [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, nan], 'Exact': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 65.0], 'Near': [0.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 30.0], 'No': [100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0], 'Size': [10.0, 100.0, 500.0, 1000.0, 5000.0, 10.0, 100.0, 500.0, 1000.0, 5000.0, 5.0], 'Type': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'All']})

df = df.set_index(['Type','Size'])
df.columns.name = 'Found'

subtotals = df.groupby(level=['Type']).mean()
subtotals = subtotals.loc[subtotals.index != 'All']
label_order = ['{}{}'.format(pre,label) for label in subtotals.index for pre in ['', 'Total_']] + ['All']
subtotals.index = ['Total_{}'.format(label) for label in subtotals.index]
subtotals['Size'] = ''

df = pd.concat([df.reset_index('Size'), subtotals], axis=0, sort=False)
df = df.loc[label_order]
df = df.set_index('Size', append=True)
```

yields

```
                  All  Exact   Near     No
        Size                              
X       10.0    100.0    0.0    0.0  100.0
        100.0   100.0    0.0  100.0    0.0
        500.0   100.0    0.0  100.0    0.0
        1000.0  100.0    0.0  100.0    0.0
        5000.0  100.0    0.0  100.0    0.0
Total_X         100.0    0.0   80.0   20.0
Y       10.0    100.0    0.0  100.0    0.0
        100.0   100.0    0.0    0.0  100.0
        500.0   100.0    0.0  100.0    0.0
        1000.0  100.0    0.0  100.0    0.0
        5000.0  100.0    0.0  100.0    0.0
Total_Y         100.0    0.0   80.0   20.0
All     5.0       NaN   65.0   30.0  100.0
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thanks for your answer. However, it does not seem to work in my situation. I didn't mention that my dataframe is way bigger than just Size, Type and Found. Even if I only take this subset only, I get index errors, because the dataframe is build slightly differently. Because the other solution by @Wan works with my database structure, I will keep that as my answer, but others might prefer this solution. Thanks for adding your thoughts here.